# illegal character in jquery/java Script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have problem with function parameter which i have passed.

```
function SearchContact(admin@yourstore.com,John Smith,12345678)
{
....code here-...
}
```

when see in firebug/console, It give me error that is

```
SyntaxError: illegal character
```

for more clarity please see in picture[image]

please give me solution.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You put values instead of parameters

Comment: Strings in Javascript are wrapped in quotes. `"` or `'`

Comment: this string comes from onclick event of button so i don't know to handle that

Comment: then show the `onclick event of button`

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the function parameter in this way

```
function SearchContact(email,name,value)
{
....code here-...
}
```

Call the function by passing actual values

```
SearchContent('admin@yourstore.com','John Smith',12345678)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should define the function like this

```
function SearchContact(email, name, number)
{
....code here-...
}
```

You then need invoke the function like this.

```
SearchContact('admin@yourstore.com','John Smith', 12345678);
```

if you want to invoke the function on the click of a button you should do something like this:

```
<button onclick="SearchContact('admin@yourstore.com','John Smith', 12345678)>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your text in quotes.
In addition if your code example is taken directly from your code you need to alter your parameter names from admin@yourstore.com to "email"